# Add AWS client in custom Android build

Tags: android, makefile

I need to install AWS client in custom Android OS.
Found source code of AWS client from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli)

Can anyone have Idea how to write make file to integrate with source code of Android?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Python client for the backend, you need to use AWS for [Android SDK](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android)

Comment: I think this is for Android application to use AWS API. But I want a command line interface so that I can do operation on adb shell

Comment: You can't add this to Android app

Comment: Okay, so can you please give some hint how can I integrate this SDK with AOSP source code? @Ihor Bykov

Comment: Download the library and add it as a module

Comment: Thanks @Ihor Bykov can you please give more explanation from where I can download this library and how to create make file(Android.mk) to add this as a module in Android OS build ?